# When starting Android studio project, intent filter does not start from given page

Tags: java, android

I want the first LoginActivity.java page to open in my project, but AnasayfaActivity.java opens. I couldn't solve the problem. I use Android Studio. I am learning Android, and I would be glad if you help. I shared LoginActivity and AndroidManifest pages. When the application is opened for the first time, the Home Activity opens, when I go back, it goes to the LoginActivity.java page.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geziproject">

    >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Geziproject">
        <activity android:name=".AnasayfaActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Geziproject.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".bos" />
        <activity android:name=".kayitol" />
        <activity android:name=".kullanicigiris" />
       
    </application>
</manifest>
```

LoginActivity.java:

```java
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button signInButton;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Button signout;
    Button btngiris;
    Button btnkayit;
    private EditText txtad;
    private EditText txtemail;
    private EditText txtsifre;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Button btngiris = findViewById(R.id.btngiris);
        Button btnkayit = findViewById(R.id.btnkayit);


        txtemail = findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
        txtsifre = findViewById(R.id.txtsifre);
        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.signin);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
       // signout = findViewById(R.id.sign_out);

        btngiris.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String email=txtemail.getText().toString();
            String pwd= txtsifre.getText().toString();
            if(email.isEmpty()){
                txtemail.setError("Lütfen email giriniz");
                txtemail.requestFocus();
            }
            else if(pwd.isEmpty()){
                txtsifre.setError("Lütfen şifre giriniz");
                txtsifre.requestFocus();
            }
            else if(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Bu alanlar boş bırakılamaz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())){
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, task -> {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Giriş  başarısız ,tekrar deneyiniz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Giriş  başarılı",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        txtemail.setText("");
                        txtsifre.setText("");

                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,AnasayfaActivity.class));
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Hata oluştu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        btnkayit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent i= new Intent(LoginActivity.this,kayitol.class);
            startActivity(i);
        });


        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("1088981466528-8pkjha8350r2uniqg2425nv5itvgpvr7.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(v -> signIn());


        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AnasayfaActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

        }
    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 100);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            //handleSignInResult(task);

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String s = "Google sign in Successful";
                displayToast(s);
                try {
                    GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "giriş başarılı", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (account != null) {
                        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
                        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnasayfaActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        }

    }

    private void displayToast(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the LoginActivity class please?

Comment: I shared LoginActivity

Answer (score 2):

As you set the launch activity in mainfest to `LoginActivity`, the app starts normally with the `LoginActivity`, but before the `LoginActivity` is resumend (i.e. shown on the screen) you added a condition in `onCreate()` method to launch the `AnasayfaActivity` as below:

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AnasayfaActivity.class)
                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

}
```

If the `user` is not null (i.e. already logged-in), then the app goes directly to `AnasayfaActivity` activity without showing the `LoginActivity` to the user.

And the reason when you go back; the app go to the `LoginActivity`, because the `LoginActivity` is still in the back stack. If you want to remove the `LoginActivity` from the back stack then add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to the intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AnasayfaActivity.class)
                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```